# How run clang from command line on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, clang

At the Going Native conference last week, Chandler Carruth announced the existence of prebuilt binaries for running clang on windows. The same information is in a blog post [here](http://blog.llvm.org/search/label/Clang). The intended audience for this is users of Visual Studio, but I want to run clang from the command line.

I ran the installer and added the LLVM `bin` directory to my path, but when I try to compile "Hello world", I get this:

```
C:\>clang hello.cpp
hello.cpp:1:10: fatal error: 'iostream' file not found
#include <iostream>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I can't find any information on how to configure things to run clang on Windows, and I'm guessing that after I figure out how to tell clang where to search for standard library headers, I'll have to tell it where to look for libraries to link with. Can somebody walk me through the setup step by step or point me to such a walkthrough?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `clang++`? Not sure it matters, though.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Same result with clang++ (which is exactly the same size as clang.exe).

Comment: Alright. Second idea: search the path where `iostream` is located, and add it to `clang++` flags with `-I`

Comment: It's only an alpha release, and they're "able to build a trivial C++ application". The intended audience is actually "developers interested in helping us track down and understand bugs". Unless you are such a developer, you should wait at least until there's a beta release.

Comment: I guess you should first run `VS2012 x86 Native Tools Command Prompt` or things like this, add `clang++.exe` to the path, and then try it.

Comment: Clang on Windows is a work in progress and Chandler Carruth said in his Going Native 2013 talk that iostreams was one of the things that do not currently work.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I am still getting errors like this with LLVM 3.4 for Windows, for instance with stdio.h in a c (not c++) file

Comment: I gave up. I want to run Clang on Windows, but I don't have time for a research project. I'll wait for others to do the heavy lifting for me.

Answer (score 22):

This is a old question, and a lot has changed since then. Given this is a common problem when trying Clang on Windows, it deserves an updated answer.

As of 2017, with the LLVM 3.9.1 build for Windows, you need the following to be able to invoke `clang` from your shell.

## VC++ Build Tools

We still do not have a libc++ port for Windows, so Clang uses the VC++ libraries as well as the VC++ linker.

So first of all you need the [VC++ Build Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=buildtools) on your system. Do note you already have those installed if you happen to have the Visual C++ IDE.

## Environment Variables

You need to tell Clang where to find the build tools and its libraries.

### Option 1 (vcvarsall.bat)

This is the easiest and standard option.

Run

`> "%VS140COMNTOOLS%../../VC/vcvarsall.bat" amd64`

Replacing `amd64` with your target architecture on Clang, which may be `x86`, `amd64` or `arm`. You may replace `%VS140COMNTOOLS%` as well if you have a different version of the VC++ toolset.

As a shortcut, you could run the Visual C++ Command Prompt instead of `cmd+vcvarsall`, since you need to call this batch for every command prompt you open.

Now you are able to **enjoy** Clang.

### Option 2 (Manually)

In case you cannot run `vcvarsall.bat` or want to automate this process, welcome, I had the same need.

All of the following environments variables are set automatically by `vcvarsall.bat`, so you can run that and take your machine values from there. I'll give mines as examples and in the hope it's the same elsewhere.

Set the `INCLUDE` environment variable to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt;`

Set `LIB` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\LIB\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.10240.0\ucrt\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\lib\winv6.3\um\x64;`. Do note the architecture specific components!

For the build tools, you can either have the tools on `PATH` or setup the `VCINSTALLDIR` environment variable. Clang will try both, favoring `VCINSTALLDIR`.

Set `VCINSTALLDIR` to `%VS140COMNTOOLS%../../VC` or add `%VS140COMNTOOLS%../../VC/bin/amd64` to your `PATH`.

## Footnote

This is all very under documented, so the requirements may change at any time, but the [Clang MSVC driver](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Driver/MSVCToolChain.cpp) is trying to automate this as much as possible, by querying the Windows Register and many other tricks, so none of this may be necessary anymore in the future.

Comment: Are you sure Clang actually reads those environment variables? Or are you assuming some build system that does.

Comment: Also if I do it via command line flags I still get errors - `expected ';' after to level declarator expanded from '_CRT_BEGIN_C_HEADER'` in `vcruntime.h` and many more.

Comment: @Timmmm Yes, quite sure, you can read some of the MSVC driver [here](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Driver/ToolChains/MSVC.cpp) and search for those environment vars. Currently using `clang++` directly, so yeah, no build system. I got the Win64 installer from [releases.llvm.org](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html), tested with Clang 3.9.1 and 4.0.0.

Comment: I think the ideal way is using vswhere to get the paths.

Answer (score 8):

If you are not restricted to use Microsoft compilers. You can use clang with MinGW-w64. Just install the [latest version](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases) of [llvm binary for Windows](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/download/llvmorg-14.0.0/LLVM-14.0.0-win64.exe) and [MinGW-w64](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/).

You can use the following code to compile your source file

```
clang++ -target x86_64-pc-windows-gnu test.cc -o test.exe
```

Comment: This gets rid of the warning "unable to find a Visual Studio installation" but it still can't find stdio.h on my PC

Comment: Maybe you can try to use `clang` instead of `clang++`

Comment: What is the equivalent of `\MD` and `\MT` in `clang` (Not `clang-cl`)?

Answer (score 1):

With Clang for Windows 5.0.0 (64 Bit) (latest versions available [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases); you want `LLVM-x.y.z-win64.exe`) and Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition or Build Tools installed in their default setup paths (including the latest/matching Windows SDK):

```
C:\>clang --version
clang version 5.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_500/final)
Target: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin
```

I've made good experiences using [`clang-cl`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/MSVCCompatibility.html) (`clang-cl.exe` == `clang.exe --driver-mode=cl`) which does find all the necessary `msvc` library/include dependencies automatically:

```
C:\>clang-cl hello.cpp
```

Or to compile as 32 or 64 Bit application:

```
C:\>clang-cl -m32 hello.cpp
C:\>clang-cl -m64 hello.cpp
```

**Alternative**

See [Arvid Gerstmann's Blog: Using clang on Windows](https://arvid.io/2017/08/03/using-clang-on-windows/).

**References**

- [How do I tell CMake to use Clang on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171878/how-do-i-tell-cmake-to-use-clang-on-windows)
- [Building a x86 application with CMake, Ninja and Clang on x64 Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47581784/building-a-x86-application-with-cmake-ninja-and-clang-on-x64-windows)
- [How do I tell CMake to use Clang on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171878/how-do-i-tell-cmake-to-use-clang-on-windows)

Comment: What is the equivalent of `\MD` and `\MT` in `clang` (Not `clang-cl`)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to use the *clang* compiler from the terminal on Windows 10:

1. I downloaded and installed the [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/). This installs and opens the *Visual Studio Installer*.
2. In the *Visual Studio Installer* I selected three things:

   1. **Desktop development with C++** from the *Workload* tab
   2. **C++ Clang Compiler for Windows (13.0.1)** from the *Individual Components* tab.
   3. **C++ Clang-cl for v143 build tools (x64/x86)** from the *Individual Components* tab.
3. Then I added the path to *clang.exe* and *clang++.exe* to my PATH environment variable. For me the path was *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin*.

After doing this, I was able to use the clang compiler from the terminal. To compile a C program, go to the source directory and type;

```
clang *.c
```

To compile a C++ program, use instead;

```
clang++ *.cpp
```

I hope this information is useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal.

Given that this problem is never solved, and who still uses bat files and cmd.exe ?

I'm providing a better solution.

Accordingly to this post on [visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/how-to-use-msvc-installed-c-clang-tools-for-window/875419), they forgot to add the path to either some *env variable* or the `path` itself.

But, don't be afraid, there's a simple and correct way using `vswhere`.

I also provide `Enter-DevShell` which is much easier to use now from `Powershell`.

```
function Get-VsWhere {
    param (
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "1")][String] $component,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "1")][String] $find,
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = "2")][String] $property
    )
    if (-not (Get-Command ./.build/vswhere.exe -ea Ignore)) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory ./.build/ -Force | Out-Null
        Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/releases/download/3.1.7/vswhere.exe -OutFile ./.build/vswhere.exe
    }
    $vswhere = (Get-Item ./.build/vswhere.exe).FullName
    if ($find) {
        & $vswhere -latest -requires $component -find $find
    }
    elseif ($property) {
        & $vswhere -latest -property $property
    }
}


function Get-Clang {
    if (-not $script:_clang) {
        $script:_clang = Get-VsWhere `
            -component Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Llvm.Clang `
            -find '**/x64/**/clang.exe'
    }
    $script:_clang
}

$clang = Get-Clang
Add-PathVariable (Split-Path -Parent $clang)

# Add-PathVariable is from PSCX, it does what's on the label


function Get-DevShell {
    if (-not $script:_devshell) {
        $script:_devshell = Get-VsWhere `
            -component 'Microsoft.Component.MSBuild' `
            -find 'Common7/Tools/Microsoft.VisualStudio.DevShell.dll'
    }
    $script:_devshell
}

function Enter-DevShell {
    $module = Get-DevShell
    Import-module $module | Out-Null
    $vsinstall = Get-VsInstallPath

    Enter-VsDevShell -VsInstallPath $vsinstall -SkipAutomaticLocation | Out-Null
}
```

---

Related Questions:

[What is the official way to access the Visual Studio 2019 version of clang from the command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59316239/what-is-the-official-way-to-access-the-visual-studio-2019-version-of-clang-from/)