# Can I use a different C standard library without re-compiling the compiler?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I just read [this about C standard library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59019932/what-standard-c-library-does-clang-use-glibc-its-own-or-some-other-one):

> When compiling C code, the C standard library cannot be switched per-compilation. It is necessary to build the entire compiler toolchain for the selected C library. That means either cross-compilation, or, in case of Linux, compiling in a distribution that uses the chosen C library. If I wanted to compile with musl, I'd compile in Alpine Linux, and so on.

Is this correct? My gut feeling is that, since libc is just a library, it should be possible to select a different one to compile and link against without modifying the compiler itself (if this is true, please tell me how). But I've seen system triplet such as `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu` and `x86_64-pc-linux-musl`, which suggests that cross-compilation is necessary.

Also, in the official [GCC install guide](https://gcc.gnu.org/install/prerequisites.html):

> In order to build GCC, the C standard library and headers must be present for all target variants for which target libraries will be built (and not only the variant of the host C++ compiler).

If libc can be swapped per-compilation, then only library and headers for the host should be necessary (for building and linking the compiler itself).

I tried compiling programs with `-nostdinc -nostdlib -isystem /path/to/libc/include -L/path/to/libc/lib`. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't (for reasons I've yet to understand).

Comment: Re “My gut feeling is that, since libc is just a library…”: “libc” is not a specific thing. The C standard contains specifications for how library routines behave. An implementation of those specifications is a specific thing. Implementations of the library may vary. Implementations may differ in what machines and operating systems they are written for. Implementations may vary in how they pass arguments and return values, using different ABIs (Application Binary Interfaces).

Comment: The compiler and its accompanying library are considered a single unit and each is allowed to rely on internal details of the other. For example, compilers often insert calls to undocumented library functions, which naturally requires that you link with the specific partner library. Conversely, the library may rely on compiler implementation details such as calling conventions and memory ordering.

Comment: A standard C library implementation is written for a specific C implementation. Different C implementations may have different widths for `int` and `long` and other types, as long as they meet the minimum requirements. You can even have multiple different C implementations on the same processor with the same operating system and ABI (with different binds from the C types to the ABI types). GCC specifies certain interactions between the compiler and the library headers.

Comment: Yes it is correct. For example many years ago I had to port gcc to a new platform with an existing libc. I had to change something in the FP function calling sequence generation from the default to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My gut feeling is that, since libc is just a library, it should be possible to select a different one to compile and link against without modifying the compiler itself (if this is true, please tell me how).

It is conceivable that a C implementation could be designed such that the standard library functions and external objects are contained in a modular library, such that different implementations could be swapped in at compile and / or runtime.  Note, however, that

1. that involves two different senses of the word "library".  What is usually meant by the term "C standard library" is not a binary object such as can serve as input to a linker.  Rather, it is a somewhat abstract collection of types, functions, objects, and macros to which every conforming C implementation provides a well-defined interface.
2. because conforming C implementations are required to include an implementation of the C standard library, there is considerable advantage to establishing deep connections between the toolchain and standard library implementation.  For instance, the compiler might perform certain optimizations whose correctness depends on implementation details of library functions, or it might serve certain objectives by synthesizing calls to internal, implementation-specific functions best characterized as implementation details of the C standard library.  Implementations don't *have* to do such things, but they can, and often do.
3. to any extent that an implementation provided for swappable standard libraries, there would still be limits to that.  Any C standard library implementation must be compatible with the executable format, ABI, and (for hosted implementations) the underlying hardware and OS of the target machine.
4. on the other hand, there actually is a degree of modularity in practice with many implementations.  For example, dynamically-linked binaries built against one version of Glibc will usually work correctly when transferred to systems that provide more recent versions of Glibc (all else being equal).

Overall, no, your gut is misleading you.  Although it is conceivable that what you describe would be possible in some cases, you're unlikely in practice to run into an implementation that allows it, except in the limited sense already described.  C toolchains ordinarily are tightly linked to specific standard library implementations.

Comment: `C toolchains ordinarily are tightly linked to specific standard library implementations.` But Clang claims to support [a wide variety of C standard library implementations](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/Toolchain.html#c-standard-library).

Comment: Suppose I implemented my own C standard library without any compiler-specific code (like musl), do you mean I cannot use it with any existing compilers (not even by re-building them from source?)

Comment: @Yizhe, Clang is one C compiler (not even a complete toolchain, though the LLVM project does provide a linker too).  That it is unusual in this regard does not contradict what I said.

Comment: @Yizhe, the main problem is not the standard library implementation being specific to the toolchain (though that can, in principle, happen too).  It is that the toolchain is, *ordinarily*, specific to the standard library implementation. You might or might not be able to deal with that in particular cases by rebuilding the toolchain. You might occasionally not have that issue at all. In general, it is not safe to assume *a priori* that a random specific toolchain can be made to work with a random specific standard library implementation.